# MySQLdb connection problems

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I'm having trouble with the MySQLdb module.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = 'localhost', 
    user = 'root', 
    passwd = '', 
    db = 'testdb', 
    port = 3000)
```

(I'm using a custom port)

the error I get is:

```
Error 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Which doesn't make much sense since that's the default connection set in my.conf.. it's as though it's ignoring the connection info I give..

The mysql server is definitely there:

```
[root@baster ~]# mysql -uroot -p -P3000
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19
Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> use testdb;
Database changed
mysql>
```

I tried directly from the python prompt:

```
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', passwd='', port=3000, host='localhost', db='pyneoform')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 74, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 169, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)")
>>>
```

I'm confused... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the mysql server is listening for tcp connections, which you can do with netstat -nlp (in *nix). This is the type of connection you are attempting to make, and db's normally don't listen on the network by default for security reasons. Also, try specifying --host=localhost when using the mysql command, this also try to connect via unix sockets unless you specify otherwise. If mysql is **not** configured to listen for tcp connections, the command will also fail.

Here's a relevant section from the [mysql 5.1 manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) on unix sockets and troubleshooting connections. Note that the error described (2002) is the same one that you are getting.

Alternatively, check to see if the module you are using has an option to connect via unix sockets (as David Suggests).

Comment: Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3300                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5361/mysqld

Comment: Yeah, my bad, in the examples above I wrote port 3000. I fixed that.. and strangely, the problem persists. heh. ugh.

Comment: Have you restarted the server since you updated the configuration?

Comment: I restarted earlier today..  but I didn't modify the server, I just updated the script to use 3300 instead of 3000 (that was a mistake in the code).

Comment: I just noticed something weird..

[root@baster httpd]# mysql -uroot -p -P666
Enter password: 
mysql>

Apparently mysql ignores my port number.. :|

Comment: I think that unless you specify a host, it connects via unix socket by default. Try using -h or --host as above, this should also make the command fail.

Comment: [root@baster httpd]# mysql -uroot -p -P3000 -h=localhost
Enter password: 
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '=localhost' (2)
[root@baster httpd]# 

Aha.

Comment: Cancel that. I'm stupid.

[root@baster httpd]# mysql -uroot -p -P3300 -hlocalhost
Enter password: 
mysql>

Comment: I checked my.conf, "skip-networking" isn't there either. This is so weird.

Comment: Have you tried to connect with your code again, using port 3300?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work..  I did get it to work by putting in the unix_socket however..  but this is really weird that it wont work outside of the socket..  boo.

Comment: Yeah, probably, I'm new to linux in general, so sockets are a bit strange for me.. I'm used to doing everything over TCP/IP.

Comment: Yup! Just found out. Mysql ignores custom ports and goes to socket mode if you use "localhost" and not "127.0.0.1".

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8d4ic/im_new_to_python_wheres_the_best_placeforum_to/c08wy9s

Answer (score 55):

Changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` solved my problem using `MySQLdb`:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = '127.0.0.1', 
    user = 'root', 
    passwd = '', 
    db = 'testdb', 
    port = 3000)
```

Using `127.0.0.1` forces the client to use TCP/IP, so that the server listening to the TCP port can pickle it up. If `host` is specified as `localhost`, a Unix socket or pipe will be used.

Comment: yes, this is especially tricky: a request for a TCP connection over 'localhost' triggers a unix socket error.

Comment: amazing, this solved my problem too! This works with XAMPP and Big Brother Bot (B3)!

Comment: Alternatively, you could find out where your MySQL unix socket is, and specify it using `unix_socket=/path/to/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 12):

add `unix_socket='path_to_socket'` where `path_to_socket` should be the path of the MySQL socket, e.g. `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock`

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue where the unix socket file was some place else, python was trying to connect to a non-existing socket. Once this was corrected using the unix_socket option, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql uses sockets when the host is 'localhost' and tcp/ip when the host is anything else.  By default Mysql will listen to both - you can disable either sockets or networking in you my.cnf file (see mysql.com for details).

In your case forget about the port=3000 the mysql client lib is not paying any attention to it since you are using localhost and specify the socket as in unix_socket='path_to_socket'.

If you decided to move this script to another machine you will need to change this connect string to use the actual host name or ip address and then you can loose the unix_socket and bring back the port.  The default port for mysql is 3306 - you don't need to specify that port but you will need to specify 3000 if that is the port you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the python connector can ONLY connect to mysql through a internet socket: unix sockets (the default for the command line client) is not supported.

In the CLI client, when you say "-h localhost", it actually interprets localhost as "Oh, localhost? I'll just connect to the unix socket instead", rather than the internet localhost socket.

Ie, the mysql CLI client is doing something magical, and the Python connector is doing something "consistent, but restrictive".

Choose your poison. (Pun not intended ;) )

Comment: This is completely wrong. If you try to connect to `127.0.0.1` you will connect via TCP/IP. If you try to connect to `localhost`, you will connect via unix sockets. The default socket for MySQL is usually `/tmp/mysql.sock`, but if your socket is somewhere else, you have to specify where it is using `unix_socket='/path/to/mysql.sock`

Comment: Note: this also depends on which library you do use.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try adding the keyword parameter `unix_socket = None` to `connect()`?

Comment: Just tried that, it doesn't like None, so I did '' instead and now it complains that '' isn't a valid socket. weird, it's like it only wants to connect via socket..