# How to connect to MariaDB by means of python?

Tags: python, mariadb

I am trying to retrieve some data from a MariaDB server (located in a different network).
I can access the server via phpmyadmin but I cannot connect to it by means of a python script.
Following [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/) I wrote the following Python code:

```
# Module Imports
import mariadb
import sys

# Connect to MariaDB Platform
try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="myUSER",
        password= "myPSW",
        host="localhost"
        port=3306,
        database="myDATABASE"

    )
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

# Get Cursor
cur = conn.cursor()
```

This is not working and I get the following error:

```
Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I retrieved MariaDB infos from here:

[image]

Am I missing some important point?

Comment: Some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758819/mysqldb-connection-problems) may help.  Note that the server is using a UNIX socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` solved my problem.

Install MariaDB Connector/C, which is a dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev
```

Use PIP to install MariaDB Connector/Python.

```
pip3 install mariadb
```

Both of these work for me:

```py
import mariadb
import sys

try:
    # connection parameters
    conn_params = {
        'user' : "harley",
        'password' : "KTJ7UCS74mv]hh[I",
        'host' : "127.0.0.1",
        'port' : 3306,
        'database' : "phishing_emails"
    }

    # establish a connection
    connection = mariadb.connect(**conn_params)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)
    
print(cursor)
```

Or...

```py
import mariadb
import sys

# Connect to MariaDB Platform
try:
    connection = mariadb.connect(
        user = "harley",
        password = "KTJ7UCS74mv]hh[I",
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        port = 3306,
        database = "phishing_emails"

    )
    
    # Get Cursor
    cursor = connection.cursor()

except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

print(cursor)
```